# Towel hairs taking up too much gpu memory

Tags: gpu

I have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 750 GPU with two gigabytes of memory.  I followed Andrew Price's Tutorial on how to make realistic towels in Blender, and I was only able to do 700,000 hairs (before my GPU ran out of memory), instead of the 1,000,000 hairs that he did.  As a result, mine didn't look as realistic.  I'm working on a bathroom interior, and I'm wondering if there is anyway to achieve a similar result without using a hair particle system?  It's okay if it doesn't look good close up, it will be farther away from my camera in the scene.  Thanks!

Comment: For distance shots, I find a good displacement texture does the trick quite well for not quite so "fuzzy" cloth types

Comment: GPU rendering is sometimes faster, but is indeed limited to the available memory on the cards, which is usually limited, To render scenes that require more memory render using CPU.

Comment: Are you using Children?

Comment: @Drudge I don't believe so, what are children?

Comment: Children are instances of the parents. If you use less parents and more children, it will take less memory. There is a children tab in the particle settings. Read more about them here: https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/children.html

Comment: @Drudge , Okay good to know.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like what is shown here http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing/

You could change the random seen on the particle system on a second layer and disable emitter visibility for one layer.

Comment: Please add more to your answer, if the link path changes, your answer's value is greatly diminished.